# EntityReference and custom field but not Title

Tags: entities

By default EntityReference (auto-complete) works with Title, is it possible to use another field (f.x. from selected Content Type)?

I also tried to create a view and use it (it worked well when you selected value) however once you save a Node and reload, it display Title again.

How could I change that and display my own field?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for the [Entity Reference autofill module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill).

Please excuse me if I misunderstood your need.

Comment: Hi
I tried it before, it suppose to do what I need, however it did not work :(